# set ComboBox selected item by Key not by value c#

Tags: c#, combobox, windows

Before post this question ,I believe it is simple issue , I search for the answer and didn't find suitable solution.

in my daily work , I am working with web applications and can easily get or set values of dropdownlists

i can not do the same in windows application C#

I have combobox and class comboItem

```
 public class ComboItem
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public ComboItem(int key, string value)
        {
            Key = key; Value = value;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }
```

Say the combobox is binded through hard code and the values are

- Key : 1  / Value : Male
- Key : 2  / Value : Female
- Key : 3  / Value : Unknown

lets say i have the Key =3 and I want to set this item ( whose key is 3 ) through code
so when form is loaded , the selected value by default will be Unknown.

```
combobox1.selectedValue =3 //Not Working , selectedValue used to return an object
combobox1.selectedIndex = 2 //Working as 2 is the index of key 3/Unknown
```

but lets say i don't know the index , how can i get the index of item whose key = 3 ?

index can be get through value in this way

```
int index = combobox1.FindString("Unknown") //will return 2
```

FindString take a value not a key , i need something like FindString which take a key and return index

NOTE : 
Here is how i bind my drop down menu

```
 JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                        jsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;

                        var empResult= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        List<Emp> Emps= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Emp[]>(empResult, jsonSerializerSettings).ToList();
                        foreach (var item in Emps)
                        {
                            ComboItem CI = new ComboItem(int.Parse(item.ID), item.Name);
                            combobox1.Items.Add(CI);
                        }
                        this.combobox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
                        this.combobox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Comment: Windows Forms? WPF? Or ?

Comment: Windows Forms C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `ValueMember` property so the `ComboBox` knows what property to deal with when `SelectedValue` is being used. By default the `ValueMember` will be empty. So when you set the `SelectedValue`, the `ComboBox` does not know what you want to set.

```
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Normally, you would also set the `DisplayMember` property:

```
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

If you do not set it, it will just call `ToString()` on the object and display that. In your case the `ToString()` returns the `Value`.

> how can i get the index of item whose key = 3 ?

If you want the item whose key is 3, why do you need to get it from the combobox? You can just get it from the collection the combobox is bound to:

For example, imagine this:

```
var items = new List<ComboItem> { new ComboItem(1, "One"),
    new ComboItem( 2, "Two") };

this.comboBox1.DataSource = items;
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";

this.comboBox1.SelectedValue = 2;
```

If I need the item whose key is 2, then this will achieve that:

```
// Use Single if you are not expecting a null
// Use Where if you are expecting many items
var itemWithKey2 = items.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == 2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodingYoshi  and really nice info , the reason why I need to get it from the combobox is that i try to get it in different place / function  than where it was bound , Do you have any idea ?

Comment: i tried this comboSubscriptionType.SelectedValue = 12  and after debugging this line the SelectedValue still null  , i add comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
in the place where i bind it

Comment: Do you have an item with key 12? To answer your previous comment, you can always store a reference to the datasource as a class level field. Or you can cast the it from combo box like this: `(List<ComboItem>) this.comboBox1.DataSource`

Comment: yes i have item with key 12 
data source is also null
i bind this combo box this way 
(look at the question again , i update it)

Comment: @jano Do not add to combo box like that. See how I did it in my answer.

Comment: @jano See how I have a list in my example and set the datasource to the list.

Comment: i see your answer , but the items come from database not hard coded

Comment: i will try to make list

Comment: Awesome , Thanks a lot  :)